# Async functions on expressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a doubt related to async function on Express. I'm fetching some JSON from database and I'm getting the following error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

I've read a little bit about it and it seems that it's related to the function having a Finished state or something like that.

I had the following code and it was crashing my application:

```
 router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){

    atendimentos.find({}, function(err, atendimentos) {
        if(!err){
            console.log(atendimentos);
            return res.json(atendimentos);
        }
    })


    res.render('home', {user: req.user}); 
})
```

But then I changed to this code:

```
 router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){

    //Added async to the function
    atendimentos.find({}, async function(err, atendimentos) {
        if(!err){
            console.log(atendimentos);
            return res.json(atendimentos);
        }
    })


    res.render('home', {user: req.user}); 
})
```

The application stopped crashing but the error continues. I don't know why. Maybe I could get some help handling this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `.then(function() { res.render('home', {user: req.user});` (right after the parenthesis closing args of find method)?

Comment: What does your route controller do? Return some json formatted data or render a html view? You "can't" do both (you may return a html view with the json as context data)

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense, I have to do just ONE thing, I render the page OR I send the data. I'll try to separate the routes or something like that, thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`res.json()` sends the response (formatted as JSON).

`res.render()` sends the response (using other formatting methods).

You can't send two responses to the same request.

Pick one.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But how do I render the view then? I need to fetch the data to this /home route. It's a login page that will render a chart in the future, that's why I'm making the JSON request on the route. Thanks anyway, I will check it out.

Comment: @danibrum — Either (1) Put the data into your template engine and use it to render the page *or* (2) Fetch the JSON (with Ajax) from a *different URL*

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs:

## `res.render`

> Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client.

## `res.json`

> Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify().

So, as mentioned, you are sending two responses. If what you want is to have the `atendimentos` data in your view, you could pass it as a property of the object to `res.render`, something like:

```
 router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){

    //Added async to the function
    atendimentos.find({}, async function(err, atendimentos) {
        if(!err){
            console.log(atendimentos);

            res.render('home', {user: req.user, atendimentos}); 
        }
    });

});
```

Or you could just make a separate API call with `fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest` or any other way.

P.S. `async` has nothing to do with your issue, the reason it stopped crashing is that unhandled rejections do not make Node crash, this will change in a future release.

Comment: I'll check that as well. When I pass the data as you said {user: req.user, atendimentos}, the atendimentos will be in JSON already because mongoDB uses JSON on its documents I guess, so this can be a solution too. Thank you.